# Abstract Module in another JAR file

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I've been trying to figure it if it's even possible to do that with dagger-2.

Let's say you have an abstract module (because it uses generics)

```
@Module
public abstract class BaseModule<A> {
  [...]
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  A provideA() {
    return [...]
  }
}
```

This module is distributed in **its own maven artifact** (it's a common library)

Now, your main program that uses that library implements doing something like that:

```
class ImplModule extends BaseModule<Foo> {
  [...]
}
```

and

```
public class Main() {
  @Component(modules = ImplModule.class)
  interface AwesomeComponent {
    @Singleton Foo foo();
  }

  [...]
    AwesomeComponent component = DaggerAwesomeComponent.builder().build();

  // do something with component.foo()
}
```

If I move ImplModule in the same maven artifact as BaseModule, everything works like a charm.

If ImplModule is in the main application maven artifact, I get compilation errors from dagger2 like:
"Foo cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."

It feels like I'm forgetting something in Maven to make the whole thing work, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: does the main application run the dagger compler too? This is usually what I forget to add when having several modules in my app. All have to run the dagger compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end.
The provider in the abstract class was not visible from the implementation in the other package.

I made it protected and everything was cool after that.